# Globally installed npm-package not running

Tags: node.js, npm

I've just published a new package into npm, and its not running as expected.

Running globally "poker-odds-calc" will produce this error:

/c/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/poker-odds-calc: line 1: /node_modules/poker-odds-calc/dist/lib/bin/poker-odds-calc.js: No such file or directory

AppData\Roaming\npm\poker-odds-calc 
"$basedir/node_modules/poker-odds-calc/dist/lib/bin/poker-odds-calc.js"   "$@"
exit $?

The above content is the reason for why the module doesnt run as global module, but I have no clue how to force npm to add the correct content to this file.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/poker-odds-calculator/dist/bin/poker-odds-calculator.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/poker-odds-calculator/dist/bin/poker-odds-calculator.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Comment: This might also be unrelated to your module. Does your Windows username contain a space (e.g. "/c/Users/Bill Gates/AppData")? I had this similar problem when there are spaces in the path. I had to move the node installation to the root of my C drive. I have it in "/c/node/" now and I haven't had this kind of issues since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the shebang character sequence in your command-line script. Thus, NPM cannot install the binary file properly.

**Solution**

You need to add a shebang character sequence at the top of your typescript command-line source (/src/lib/bin/poker-odds-calc.ts). In other words, the top of the file needs to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import * as argv from "argv";
import Table from "../Table";
import {CardsFromString, Log} from "../Utils";
```

Upon package installation, NPM will look for the first line in each file defined in package.json's "bin" config and act accordingly in your operating system. In Windows, NPM creates different types of binary files depending on what you have defined at the top. If a node shebang is present, NPM creates a binary that attempts to execute the command-line script with node (similar to the content you wished for above). If shebang is omitted, NPM creates a proxy binary that outsources the responsibility to Windows (likely to fail, as you have seen).

**Reference**

https://medium.com/netscape/a-guide-to-create-a-nodejs-command-line-package-c2166ad0452e